# quanteda - dfm (by dfm_lookup) doesn't show the columns of terms as example

Tags: r, quanteda, dfm

I am following [this](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/dfm/dfm_lookup/) tutorial to create a document-feature matrix with features defined by my dictionary. What I have now is an output of two columns giving my document ID and the frequency of all features in my dictionary.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(quanteda)

## subset data 
item7_corpus_subset <- item_7_corpus |> 
    filter(year(filing_date) == year_data) |> 
    head(100) ## edit here, comment if codes work well
    
# tokenize
item7_tokens <- tokens(item7_corpus_subset, 
                       what = "word", 
                       remove_punct = TRUE,
                       remove_symbols = TRUE,
                       remove_numbers = TRUE,
                       remove_url = TRUE) |> 
    tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3)
       
## count words from dictionary
item7_doc_dict <- item7_tokens |> 
    dfm(tolower = TRUE) |> 
    dfm_lookup(dictionary = cyber_dict, levels = 1:3)
print(item7_doc_dict)
```

```
## Document-feature matrix of: 100 documents, 1 feature (94.00% sparse) and 13 docvars.
## features
## docs                                        cyber_dict
## 1000015_10K_1999_0000912057-00-014793.txt          0
## 1000112_10K_1999_0000930661-00-000704.txt          0
## 1000181_10K_1999_0001000181-00-000001.txt          0
## 1000227_10K_1999_0000950116-00-000643.txt          0
## 1000228_10K_1999_0000889812-00-001326.txt          0
## 1000230_10K_1999_0001005150-00-000103.txt          0
## [ reached max_ndoc ... 94 more documents ]
```

I want to see the frequency of each keyword rather than the total frequency of all keywords that I have.  I am trying to emulate the tutorial which generated that as:

```r
dfmat_irish_lg <- dfm_lookup(dfmat_irish, dictionary = dict_lg, levels = 1)
print(dfmat_irish_lg)
```

```
## Document-feature matrix of: 14 documents, 9 features (19.84% sparse) and 6 docvars.
##                       features
## docs                   CULTURE ECONOMY ENVIRONMENT GROUPS INSTITUTIONS LAW_AND_ORDER RURAL URBAN VALUES
##   Lenihan, Brian (FF)        9     583          21      0           93            11     9     0     19
##   Bruton, Richard (FG)      35     201           5      0           95            14     0     0     14
##   Burton, Joan (LAB)        33     400           6      3           84             6     2     3      6
##   Morgan, Arthur (SF)       56     427          10      0           63            22     2     1     18
##   Cowen, Brian (FF)         16     416          24      0           63             4     8     1     13
##   Kenny, Enda (FG)          26     211           8      1           53            18     0     2      8
## [ reached max_ndoc ... 8 more documents ]
```

Comment: Without access to `item_7_corpus`,`year_data`, and `cyber_dict`, it is hard to diagnose problems like this.  Can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @mikael-jagan, thanks for considering my issue. 
The issue here is to separate the columns by keywords (like the tutorial example, each column captures the frequency of each word) rather than only aggregated frequency in only one of the whole dictionary `cyber_dict` like what I have.

Comment: You need to edit the question and add the relevant code there. In a new R process, I should be able to run all of the code without errors and reproduce the output you've shown us.

Comment: Thanks, you can see an example in @kohei 's comment below (similar to what I have posted in GitHub). Can you help me to separate each keyword into one column instead of separating it into sub-dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

There were three mistakes:

- `tokens_ngrams()` is used before dictionary analysis
- there is only one group (key) in the dictionary
- if `exclusive = FALSE`, all other words are included

Your code should be

```r
require(quanteda)
#> Loading required package: quanteda
#> Package version: 3.2.3
#> Unicode version: 13.0
#> ICU version: 69.1
#> Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
# create a sample corpus
texts <- c("This is a sample text mentioning cyber attack.",
           "Cybersecurity is important to protect against cyber threats.",
           "The company experienced a data breach due to a cyber attack.",
           "Cyber criminals are becoming increasingly sophisticated.",
           "Protecting against cyber attacks requires a multi-layered approach.")

corpus <- corpus(texts)

dict <- dictionary(list(cyber = c("cyber", "cybersecurity", "cybercriminals"), 
                        attack = c("cyberattack", "data breach", "protect")))

toks <- quanteda::tokens(corpus)

dfmt <- dfm(toks)
dfmt
#> Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 31 features (70.97% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    this is a sample text mentioning cyber attack . cybersecurity
#>   text1    1  1 1      1    1          1     1      1 1             0
#>   text2    0  1 0      0    0          0     1      0 1             1
#>   text3    0  0 2      0    0          0     1      1 1             0
#>   text4    0  0 0      0    0          0     1      0 1             0
#>   text5    0  0 1      0    0          0     1      0 1             0
#> [ reached max_nfeat ... 21 more features ]

dfmt_dict <- dfm_lookup(dfmt, dictionary = dict, levels = 1, 
                         exclusive = TRUE, capkeys = FALSE)
dfmt_dict
#> Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 2 features (40.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    cyber attack
#>   text1     1      0
#>   text2     2      1
#>   text3     1      0
#>   text4     1      0
#>   text5     1      0
```

Comment: Hi @kohei, Thanks for considering my issue. What I see from your output is each column captures the word frequency of each sub-dictionary. I need to have each column with the frequency of each keyword ("cyber", "cybersecurity", "cybercriminals", "cyberattack", "data breach", "protect" ). How can I have it?

Comment: Hi @kohei again, You have mentioned my mistake in tokens_ngrams. 
How should I use `tokens_ngrams()` with n = 1:3 with my full dictionary has both uni/bi/ and tri-grams? Which is the right other of `tokens`, `tokens_ngrams`, `dfm`, and `dfm_lookup` in a pipeline?

Comment: I think you want: `dfm(tokens_keep(toks, dict))` to get the frequencies of your dictionary values in the dfm. You refer to these as “keywords” but in quanteda’s terminology they are dictionary values. The behaviour shown so far uses `dfm_lookup()` to return the frequency of the dictionary _keys_.

Comment: @NHH, if `tokens_ngrams(n=1)`, the dictionary values should match, but there is no point to generate ngrams that will be soon discarded. You should use `tokens_keep()` if you want the frequency of dictionary values.

Comment: thanks @KenBenoit and @Kohei for introducing tokens_keep, I haven't realized it before. Question 1: Once having a dictionary with uni/bi/trigram keys, for example, "cybersecurity", "cyber attack", and "personal information stolen". Does using `tokens_ngrams(n=1)` match all keys? OR Do have I to use `tokens_ngrams(n=1:3)`. Question 2: If `tokens_ngrams` is necessary, the order of pipeline (1) `tokens`, (2) `tokens_ngrams`, (3) `dfm`, (4) `dfm_lookup`/ or `dfm(tokens_keep)` is correct?

Comment: That's a separate question and would be better asked separately. But in short, 'tokens_lookup()' will match multi-word dictionary values. No need at all for `tokens_ngrams()`.